# reaction between semicarbazide and a mixture of cyclohexanone and benzaldehyde

Tags: organic-chemistry

Why is cyclohexane-semicarbazide precipitated, but after a while the precipitate is benzaldehyde-semicarbazide?

Comment: In what solvent is the reaction conducted?

Comment: Probably kinetic and thermodynamic control